# Random variable such that $E[X^2] = 20$...

Tags: probability, means, variance

Random variable such that $E[X^2] = 20$

My professor told me that the mean and variance are the same size. I now have to find that size. I am under the assumption that it's one, because I would conclude that the variance squared should be one if it was one before.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  $Var(x)=E[x^2]-E[x]^2$.

Comment: You should consider giving a [check mark $\checkmark$](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) to respondents.

Answer (score 5):

Use the definition of Variance, 
$$\mathsf {Var}(X)=\mathsf E[X^2]-\mathsf E[X]^2$$

... and if variance and mean are equal to $x$ then

$$x=20-x^2$$

$$x^2+x-20=0$$